How to enable ModSecurity to actually block/deny malicious requests?
I have setup installed mod security module for apache in ubuntu 22.04, using.
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2
sudo a2enmod security2
sudo systemctl restart apache2

This installs security module version 2.9.5 with core rule set version 3.3.2.
I set
SecRuleEngine On
in /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf
and keep only two conf enabled from core rule set, rest of all confs I have moved temporary.

/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/REQUEST-933-APPLICATION-ATTACK-PHP.conf
/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf

As , my goal is to set rules one by one by observing that , no any false positive / my application needs blocked.
But It is not blocking request, instead it is just being logged in mod security audit log.
I am not sure what I am missing here, rest all things are at default setup.
I can share more details as needed.
Can someone help me with this?


and keep only two conf enabled from core rule set, rest of all confs I have moved temporary.

This is the problem.
You must set up the necessary things in crs-setup.conf, or at least take a review.
Then you must also need to understand how CRS works by default - that's the "anomaly scoring mode" - here you can read about more.
A quick summary: most CRS rules don't terminate the transactions, just increase the anomaly score (this is a transaction score variable). If that reaches a previously set threshold value (see crs-setup.conf), then a specific rule terminates that.
If you remove these config files (usually REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION and RESPONSE-959-BLOCKING-EVALUATION), then your transaction won't block ever.
IMPORTANT! Anomaly scoring mode is the default mode, but you can use the traditional, "self-contained" mode too. Then you have to modify few settings in crs-setup.conf - see this section.
With self-contained mode you don't need to add other rules, each triggered rule will terminate the transaction.

Thanks @airween,
I know that most of rules are not actually denying request/response, they just increase / update the score, and the default mode is 'Anomaly scoring' mode, I don't want to change it to 'Self contained mode'.
I think I have found the issue in my configuration.
This first conf file required REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf where those anomaly score variables are initialised, I was missing that , that is why request was not blocking.
Overall by loading three conf files of crs worked for me.

/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf (responsible for variable initialisation)
/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/REQUEST-933-APPLICATION-ATTACK-PHP.conf (responsible for actual rule execution and set score accordingly)
/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf (responsible for request blocking based on score set by rules config)


So your problem has solved?

Yes it is solved now

Then you should change the issue status to solved.
